# Intersection of the Arraylists in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, compare

I've a legacy code base where I've four [ArraysLists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.collections.arraylist) (different sizes). I want to compare these four arraylists and save the same values in a separate Array/Arraylist.

The arrays can have same values multiple times since ordering is not important. You can say that I just need the intersection of the ArrayLists.

The following code works, but of-course this is not the best way to do, looping on all the arrays-

```
For i = 0 To arr.Count - 1 Step 1
   For j = 0 To arr1.Count - 1 Step 1
       If arr.Item(i) = arr1.Item(j) Then
          For k = 0 To arr2.Count - 1 Step 1
              If arr.Item(i) = arr2.Item(k) Then
                 For l = 0 To arr3.Count - 1 Step 1
                     If arr.Item(i) = arr3.Item(l) Then
                        // the value arr.Item(i) exists in all 4 arrys
                        // save this to another array
                     End If
                 Next
              End If
          Next
        End If
     Next
Next
```

Since my arrayList size could be in thousands, that's not the way I want to know how should I sort out this.

Thanks.

PS. Sorry if this is a duplicate question, since I was not able search this anywhere (I'm new to VB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `ArrayList.Contains` to shorten / simplify things:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To arr.Count - 1
     If Arr1.Contains(arr(i)) AndAlso Arr2.Contains(arr(i)) _
             AndAlso Arr3.Contains(arr(i)) AndAlso Arr4.Contains(arr(i)) Then

             // the value arr(i) exists in all 4 arrayLISTS
             // save this to another array
      End If
Next
```

Probably wont be a lot different in speed, but the code is sure easier to read.  NB: `AndAlso` is important in this because it short circuits the later tests when it the result is false.

Comment: But wont it check the values for the same index only? I'm not sure but it seems to me.

Comment: `Contains: Determines whether an element is in the System.Collections.ArrayList.`  So no, it will tell you if the given value is anywhere in the arraylist.